# Network file transfer with credential in pure .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking

Recently, I created a method to transfer file over network with credentials. For this I am using WIN-32 API LogonUser. LogonUser uses advapi32.dll. This limits us to have this dll present and supported in OS where we deploy our web application.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);


private static string CopyToNetwork(string _sourceFile, string _targetFile, string _domain, string _userName, string _password)
{
    IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
    bool returnValue = LogonUser(_userName, _domain, _password, 9, 3, ref tokenHandle);
    if(returnValue)
    {
        using(WindowsIdentity wid = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle))
        {
            using(WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = wid.Impersonate())
            {
                File.Copy(_sourceFile, _targetFile, IS_OVERWRITE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we don't want this dependency. Can we do the same using pure .Net? Meaning without using any WIN API.

Comment: On Windows advapi32.dll is always going to be present and should never be redistributed anyway.

Comment: I am planning to host web application on Linux.